# Monkey patching String with #to_ivar

Tags: ruby, cucumber, monkeypatching

I would like to monkey patch String with #to_ivar.

```
class String
  def to_ivar
    instance_variable_get("@#{self}")
  end
end
```

So that when I have an environment with instance variables like this:

```
instance variables:
  @__cucumber_runtime  @browser       @browser_type  @debug     @sauce_config  @user_A
```

I can do this in a step definition:

```
Given(/^user (.*) does something$/) do |user|
  @user = user.to_ivar
...
end
```

So I did, but, it seems that String#to_ivar does not know about the instance variables:

```
    13: def to_ivar
 => 14:   binding.pry
    15:   instance_variable_get("@#{self}")
    16: end

    [2] pry("user_A")> instance_variables
     => []
```

Is there a way for an instance of String to know about the Cucumber world and its instance variables?

Comment: You're really going against the grain here. Ruby's instance variables are specific to a context. An instance method on a String is not going to work. You need a helper method in the correct context, in this case the case definition.

Comment: You might want to pass a respective [`binding`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Binding.html) to `to_ivar`.